# Change style if expiry date is in the past - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a React app which is listing Db content, more specific creditcard data which are stored in a DB.

So far, I have the following:

**ExistingCardList class**

```
class ExistingCardList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
        this.state = {
            data : [],
            mouseOverIndex: null,
            clickedIndex: null,
            amount: null
       }
    }

  onMouseOver (index) {
    this.setState({
      mouseOverIndex: index
    })
  }

  onMouseOut (index) {
    this.setState({
      mouseOverIndex: index
    })
  }

  onClickHandler (index) {
    this.setState({
      clickedIndex: index
    })
  }

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/bla/blabla')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((findResponse) => {
            console.log(findResponse)
            this.setState({
                data : findResponse,
            })
        } )
}

render() {
    let id = 0;

    return(
       <div>
            {
              this.state.data.map((dynamicData, key) =>
                <div style={{'padding': '2px 16px'}}>
                  <ClickableBox
                    title={dynamicData.cardholder}
                    body= {['**** **** **** ', dynamicData.card_identifier]}
                    footer={dynamicData.expiration}
                    onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver.bind(this, ++id)}
                    onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut.bind(this, 0)}
                    onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this, id)}
                    mouseOver={this.state.mouseOverIndex === id}
                    clicked={this.state.clickedIndex === id}
                   />
                </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
  }
}


export default ExistingCardList;
```

and **ClickableBox class**

```
export default class ClickableBox extends React.Component {

  render () {
  let style = {
     ...STYLE.box,
     ...STYLE.disableSelect,
     ...(this.props.mouseOver ? STYLE.boxMouseOver : null)
   };

 style = {
  ...STYLE.box,
  ...(this.props.clicked ? STYLE.boxClicked : style)
};

return (
  <div style={style} onMouseOver={this.props.onMouseOver} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
    <span style={STYLE.title}>{this.props.title}</span>
    <hr style={STYLE.hLine} />
    <span style={STYLE.body}>{this.props.body}</span><br />
    <hr style={STYLE.hLine} />
    <span style={STYLE.footer}>{this.props.footer}</span>
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

This looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to change the color of the two card forms from blue to e.g grey because their expiry date is in the past?
Unfortunately, I cannot combine the two classes and do not know where to write the function which will check the date...

Can please anybody help? Thank you....

Comment: Does `dynamicData.expiration` give us month and year?

Comment: @Liam yes... MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

If this.props.footer is the date..

```
style={"is this.props.footer in past" ? expiredStyle : style}
```

EDIT:

Ok... since this.props.footer is a date as string, you can do something like this:

```
style={new Date(this.props.footer.substring(3) + '-' + this.props.footer.substring(0,2)) < new Date(new Date().getFullYear() + '-' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)) ? expiredStyle : style}
```

**To explain my code:**

Your prop that you give to the component has a date as string. You have to parse it to a date. Then you can get to date from today and compare them. If the date is in the past, it gives the style attribute the `expiredStyle` if not, the normal `style`. In addition, you have to create an expiredStyle variable.

This code isn't nearly perfect. Just a way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the meanwhile I found a similar solution. :)